# Use ArrayAdapter with ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm currently building an Android Agenda Activity which consists in 4 ListView. Basicaly, I got the method onAgendaDataReady(ArrayList appointments) that is called by a WebServiceCoordinator. This method sorts the appointments and that way, populates 4 new ArrayList. The code is the following :

```
@Override
public void onAgendaDataReady(ArrayList<Appointment> appointments) {
    //swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    alert.hide();
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentsfuturs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentspasses = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentsannules = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointmentsaconfimer = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Appointment a : appointments) {
        if (a.stateId == 2)
            appointmentsaconfimer.add(a);
        else if (a.stateId == 6)
            appointmentsannules.add(a);
        else if (a.stateId == 5)
            appointmentspasses.add(a);
        else if (a.stateId == 4)
            appointmentsfuturs.add(a);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapterfuturs = new ArrayAdapter<>(AgendaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointmentsfuturs);
    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapterpasses = new ArrayAdapter<>(AgendaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointmentspasses);
    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapterannules = new ArrayAdapter<>(AgendaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointmentsannules);
    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapteraconfirmer = new ArrayAdapter<>(AgendaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointmentsaconfimer);

    rdvFutursListView.setAdapter(adapterfuturs);
    rdvPassesListView.setAdapter(adapterpasses);
    rdvAnnulesListView.setAdapter(adapterannules);
    rdvAConfirmerListView.setAdapter(adapteraconfirmer);

    adapterfuturs.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterpasses.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapterannules.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapteraconfirmer.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This code is working, but I don't want anymore to use the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout. So I built an ArrayAdapter with a custom layout.
My problem / question is the following : how to pass the ArrayList created by onAgendaDataReady() to my Adapter ?

I tried to do this :

```
    appointmentItemAdapter = new AppointmentItemAdapter(this);
    rdvFutursListView.setAdapter(appointmentItemAdapter);
    appointmentItemAdapter.add(adapterfuturs);
```

But the appointmentItemAdapter requires an Appointment and not an ArrayList.

Thanks for your help

--------------- FINAL SOLUTION -----------------

```
AppointmentItemAdapter appointmentFutursItemAdapter = new AppointmentItemAdapter(AgendaActivity.this);
rdvFutursListView.setAdapter(appointmentFutursItemAdapter);
appointmentFutursItemAdapter.addAll(appointmentsfuturs);
appointmentFutursItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing different things here.

Your custom Adapter **has to** take an ArrayList (or any Collection) as input parameter and return the current items to the list (based on the position queried)

So it is not sufficient to pass a single Appointment as parameter.

Comment: So I have first to change my class declaration to this : `public class AppointmentItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<Appointment>>`  ?

Comment: No, ArrayAdapter<Appointment> should be fine. Have a look at the constructors of ArrayAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
It takes a list or Collection of the Type T you choose.

Comment: Yup thanks ! I was using add() instead of addAll()… It's working, thanks a lot